# How to format number to very special format in java?

Tags: java, format, number-formatting, formatter

I want to format always-11-digit integer number to format "123-456-789 12". Is there library method to do this?

EDIT: May be I can group 3 numbers with:

```
 DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
 decimalFormatSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('-');
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("000,000,000.00", decimalFormatSymbols);
```

But I can't separate two first digit with space (where '.' is now)

Comment: Probably not since it would require 10 lines of code to do it.

Comment: u mean Java isn't enough?

Comment: See the String#format answer for example

Comment: Just take care that your input might not be a number but actually be a string composed of digits. For example "000 456 789 12".

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation.
java.lang.NumberFormat  can set any one group separator, like '-' too. But I need 2 different group separator at time '-' and ' '.

Comment: @RC I don't understand how `String.format` can do it (except if you manually isolate each group of digits).

Comment: @DmitryTorshin I ended up with this solution. 1) convert your number to a string and optionally pad it with zeroes : `String numberAsStr = String.format("%011d", number);`. Then 2), use some `String.substring` : `return String.format("%s-%s-%s %s", numberAsStr.substring(0, 3), numberAsStr.substring(3, 6), numberAsStr.substring(6, 9), numberAsStr.substring(9, 11));`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yes, I don't want to separate in manualy. Hope there are better solution.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thank you. I understand this solution (I prefer to use myNumber / 1000_000_000 , myNumber / 1000_000 % 1000 etc.).

So there are no better and easier solution?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle the way you did in your comment !?

Comment: Use your decimalformat and then `.replace(".", " ")` (beware of the Locale) or something like that

Comment: @RC. Do you think it's a good way?
Ok, thank you.

Comment: I would use the substring.

Comment: @RC. Is any question about formatting numbers in Java is a duplicate of general formatting question?

Comment: @DAle do we need one question per format??

Comment: @RC., No, but that general question doesn't have an answer to this question.

Comment: `DecimalFormatSymbols s = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   s.setGroupingSeparator('-');

  DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("000,000,000");
  f.setDecimalFormatSymbols(s);
  
  return String.format("%s %02d", f.format(number / 100), number % 100);`

Comment: @DAle the duplicate already mention a lot of possibilities. Adding some research from there should be enough to answer almost every number format problem. So I don't believe this is necessary. Of course, this case is specific and need some "workaround" for every solution but that's the job of the developer to match a solution to his problem, without that, we would not have a job